# How to remove padding if the heading has no background image?

Tags: jquery

There are numerous headings and some has background image as bullets and for that purpose the headings are given `padding-left: 35px;` now by some reasons some headings hasn't background image. Thus, I wanted to remove the padding-left value by applying 0 pixel. How can I do something like this?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var ts = $('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6');
    if(!ts.style.background) ts.css({'padding-left':'0px'});
});
```

The above code didn't work. Please note: also the background image is given by using `background` or `background-image`

Comment: Did you try `.css("padding-left","0px");`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `ts` is a jQuery wrapper element it will not have the `style` property

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var ts = $('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6');
    ts.filter(function () {
        return $(this).css('background-image') == 'none'
    }).css({
        'padding-left': '0px'
    });
});
```

demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZBS3S/)

Comment: I tried your code and it also sets the padding left to 0 pixel which has background image